# python - downsampling with resample (D) skips days that don't have 00:00:00 data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, downsampling

i need to downsample a dataframe from hourly to daily. This is quite straightforward using pandas but I'm facing a problem that I'm failing to resolve.
Data frame looks like this:

| datetime | prod |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-03-13 19:00:00 | 38.700000 |
| 2018-03-13 20:00:00 | 38.700000 |
| 2018-03-14 00:00:00 | 38.600000 |
| 2018-03-15 08:00:00 | 38.200000 |
| 2018-03-15 11:00:00 | 38.100000 |
| 2018-03-15 14:00:00 | 38.100000 |
| 2018-03-15 15:00:00 | 38.100000 |
| 2018-03-15 21:00:00 | 38.100000 |
| 2018-03-16 00:00:00 | 38.000000 |
| 2018-03-16 06:00:00 | 38.000000 |
| 2018-03-16 12:00:00 | 38.000000 |
| 2018-03-16 15:00:00 | 37.900000 |
| 2018-03-16 19:00:00 | 38.000000 |
| 2018-03-16 20:00:00 | 37.900000 |
| 2018-03-17 09:00:00 | 37.900000 |
| 2018-03-17 20:00:00 | 37.700000 |

I run resample function like this:

```
df['prod'] = df['prod'].resample('24H').mean()
```

I've tried 'D' instead of '24H' and it always give me:

| datetime | prod |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-03-14 | 38.600000 |
| 2018-03-16 | 37.966667 |
| 2018-03-28 | 36.625000 |
| .... | ... |

It is missing the days that don't have values at **00:00:00**.
Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: You should not re-assign just `prod` back. You can try: `df = df.set_index('datetime').resample('D').mean()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pd.Grouper` as alternative of `resample` if `datetime` is a column and not your index.

```
out = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')).mean().reset_index()
print(out)

# Output:
    datetime       prod
0 2018-03-13  38.700000
1 2018-03-14  38.600000
2 2018-03-15  38.120000
3 2018-03-16  37.966667
4 2018-03-17  37.800000
```